# MVVM runs all view model property getters when page is constructed

Tags: maui, .net-maui, maui-community-toolkit

I'm new to .net maui mvvm and need an advise on how to handle the following scenario:
.net maui solution based on Shell with community toolkit mvvm. Page1 calls Page2 passing ObjectToPass:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(Page2), new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                [nameof(ObjectToPass)] = ObjectToPass
            });
```

Viewmodel of Page2 (Page2ViewModel) uses ObjectToPass to build bindable properties. However at the moment I run this line of code in the viewmodel constructor

```
    public BuildGamePage(Page2ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }
```

Maui runtime (or mvvm runtime) starts invoking getter of each bindable property through the reflection mechanism, even if these properties are not used in Page2 at all.

Problem here is Page2ViewModel is not ready to fetch its properties at the time (Page2 constructor) since it needs to wait ObjectToPass to be passed to fetch relevant information. So what would be the best way to handle that: should I check ObjectToPass for null in every property getter and return default value or there is a better way? And overall, why does maui mvvm needs to call each property of a view model in the page constructor when BindingContext is set, even before visual elements of the page are constructed?

**UPDATE**

Page2ViewModel getter example:

```
public string Title => $"Details of {ObjectToPass.Name} object"
```

interestingly the getter is called even if it's not used inside Page2, right after `BindingContext = viewModel;` in constructor

here's call stack with Reflection mechanism running the getters
[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I understand what you mean, but does it help if you set the binding context before `InitializeComponent`?

Comment: **Add to question the code** for one of your properties. You may need to redesign how you approach this. A getter should be very simple, and should always work at all times. Even if that means returning null. Any complexity should go into the setter and/or initialization code that runs in `ObjectToPass`s setter. It may help to add a `private bool _isReady = false;` member to Page2ViewModel. Then at end of initialization code, set `_isReady = true;`. Then you can add if-tests to skip logic that should only be done when ready.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I've updated the question. I understand I can put a null check for each getter, question rather is why does Maui do that

Comment: If it is convenient for you, could you please post a basic demo so that we can help you better?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT, you can take any mvvm demo solution, set a breakpoint at any getter property and see it hits from the constructor

Comment: `set a breakpoint at any getter property and see it hits from the constructor`  Can you give a demo code?

Comment: yes, if I set a breakpoint, it hits from `BindingContext = viewModel`. You can see it from the above screenshot of a stack trace starting from BindingContext, it sets in the constructor, the only place I set it from